# Add location and weather information to HealthKit Workout Session

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, healthkit

I am working on an app where `HealthKit` is used and `HKWorkout` sessions are created and added to the `HealthKit` store.

Now after I finished an outdoor activity with Apple's native Workout app on the Watch, (like Open Water Swimming), when I then open this workout on the Activity App on my iPhone, it tells me the location where I started the activity and the weather conditions at the time.

I've been reading through the `HealthKit` documentation but I could not find any API to add this information from my app to the `HKWorkoutSession`.

Is it possible for developers to add this to a `HKWorkout`, and if so: how?

[image: Example from Activities App on iPhone]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add weather details to your app's workouts, you must specify values for the `HKMetadataKeyWeatherCondition`, `HKMetadataKeyWeatherTemperature`, or `HKMetadataKeyWeatherHumidity` metadata keys on the saved `HKWorkout`. See the [metadata keys reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/healthkit_constants/metadata_keys) for more information.

There is no API to specify a general location for the workout. However, in watchOS 4.0 your app can now save an `HKWorkoutRoute` alongside an `HKWorkout` to provide a map of the route the user took ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutroute)).

Comment: That should be "lack of documentation" since Apple hasn't yet actually documented it.